# Examples of model-based control techniques

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory, modeling

I am trying to find out the differences between the model-based control approach and the data-driven one.
Surely the main difference is the latter's independence from the information of the mathematical model of the plant in the control design.
For the former from experimental data a model for the plant is obtained with some degree of accuracy.

If for data-driven techniques, I have found out many examples: PID, IFT, ILC, etc., I have not found out anything for the model-based control.
**Can you give me some examples of techniques (maybe the most common) that can be defined as model-based control approaches?**

Comment: You should be able to find these by searching yourself, we are not a free research service.

Comment: I have searched for a very long time, but I have not found out anything. I wanted only to know if one of you could help me with some examples...

Comment: I don't want the explanation of the theory behind them, but only some example of known techniques

Comment: I would argue that ILC is model based and PID I also wouldn't classify as a data-driven control method. I would even argue that the majority is model-based, such as LQR, MPC, H∞ and probably most of nonlinear control.

Comment: @fibonatic Are you sure? I have read many papers that refers to ILC as data driven and PID as the first example of data driven technique!

Comment: @fibonatic moreover backstepping control and sliding mode are considered model-based?

Comment: Where do you draw the between feedback and data-driven? Namely, ILC definitely needs a model, but uses a recording of the error signal to update the "feedforward" in an iterative way (so at least blurs the line between feedback and feedforward, not sure I would classify it as data-driven, not in the same sense as ML at least).

Comment: And PID is a really simple, yet powerful controller (at least the majority of the industry uses it). So due to its simplicity it can definitely also easily be used in a data-driven framework. But one can also choose its parameters using a model of the system.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129301/discussion-between-pawel-and-fibonatic).